# How can I play an ogg file from a website url in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, naudio, ogg

I have this url : `https://verses.quran.com/Shuraym/ogg/067001.ogg`
I need to play this audio on my c# WPF app without having to download it.

I've been using this for url with an mp3 file extension :

```
            // this code use NAudio
            using (var mf = new MediaFoundationReader(url))
            using (var wo = new WasapiOut())
            {
                wo.Init(mf);
                wo.Play();

                PlayingAudioWasapiOut.Add(wo);
                while (wo.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                };
            }
```

I tried the code that works for the mp3 url, but it does not work with an ogg url (it just exit the method without any error at the line 1).
I also tried using this :

```
            using (var vorbisStream = new NAudio.Vorbis.VorbisWaveReader(url))
            using (var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOutEvent())
            {
                waveOut.Init(vorbisStream);
                waveOut.Play();
                PlayingAudioWaveOutEvent.Add(waveOut);

                while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }

            }
```

But it did not work because it is made for local file audio.

Comment: Can you download the file at the URL?

Comment: In my software, you can either download the file to have it offline, or not download it if you want to have free space on your computer. The part where downloading the file and reading it works, but not the part where the file is read directly from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

I made it

```
        internal static async Task PlayOggFileFromUrl(string lien)
    {
        var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(lien);
        using (Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var vorbisStream = new NAudio.Vorbis.VorbisWaveReader(stream))
            using (var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOutEvent())
            {
                waveOut.Init(vorbisStream);
                waveOut.Play();

                while (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }

                waveOut.PlaybackStopped += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    waveOut.Dispose();
                    vorbisStream.Dispose();
                };
            }
        }
    }
```